# Append String and Variable to SQLite Column

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-update, append

I am trying to append a `string` value and a `variable` to a column in my `database`. Currently I have the following:

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Movies SET part = part || @part WHERE id = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@part", part));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", id));
    conn.Open();
}
```

However, I would like to add a `:` delimiter between the `old` and `new` values.

Eg: The current value of the column `part` is `1`. The value I want to append is `2`. So the final result in the `column` should be `1:2`.

I have tried:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Movies SET part = part || ':' + @part WHERE id = @id";
```

But this seems to add `1` and  `2` together.

Would anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Well one part already concatenated with `||` so why you using `+` to concatenate other? Shouldn't that be: `part = part || ':' || @part`? Or you can try to use `part = printf('%s:%s', part, @part)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, since `:` [behaves as a parameter in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), you can concatenate your column with `:` and your `@part` seperately like;

```
part = part || ':' || @part
```

If your part column is `1`, with this change, it should be updated as `1:2`